# .replace() is only temporary, javascript

Tags: jquery, forms

Im creating a forum page, and forming the comments section now. Since when you press return it type \n in the text area, the result of a text like this:
A 
A 
A 
Ends up like 'A A A'.
I am submitting this text to a database therefore I have to perform this function, before the submission. So I have used onsubmit on the form and directed it into the following function:

```
 function ClearText() {
    $('#CommentBox').val().replace(/\n/g,'<br>');
    console.log($('#CommentBox').val());
```

When I do this manually on the console I see that it actually converts the newline tags into br tags. However when I run this code, $('#CommentBox').val() doesnt change at all.
Is there an other way of calling a function before the submission? Or is there a way of making this .replace() change permanent? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now you are only getting the value, You should set the value,

```
 function ClearText() {
     $('#CommentBox').val($('#CommentBox').val().replace(/\n/g, '<br>'));
     console.log($('#CommentBox').val());
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

`.replace()` will not replace in actual value but will return replaced value with specified characters. You need to store it  in variable and then set it again

```
function ClearText() {
     var replaceVal = $('#CommentBox').val().replace(/\n/g,'<br>');
   $('#CommentBox').val(replaceVal )
    console.log($('#CommentBox').val());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function ClearText() {
       $('#CommentBox').val($('#CommentBox').val().replace(/\n/g,'<br>'))
       console.log($('#CommentBox').val());
    }
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so.